# Crear dos campos a partir de uno sin usark awk ni sed

Tags: linux, bash, csv, cut

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente dataset con nombre `df.csv` en Linux:

```
name,id,nametype,recclass,mass (g),fall,year,reclat,reclong,GeoLocation
Aachen,1,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775000; 6.083330)"
Aarhus,2,Valid,H6,720,Fell,01/01/1951 12:00:00 AM,56.183330,10.233330,"(56.18333; 10.233330)"
```

Se me pide pide crear un nuevo dataset `newdf.csv` que contenga los campos:

```
 name, mass (g), year, reclat, reclong, lat, long
```

Para ello, he seleccionado los campos que se me piden pero para construir `lat, long` necesito separar el campo `GeoLocation` en dos, lat i long. De esta manera el dataset nuevo quedaría algo tal que así:

```
name,id,nametype,recclass,mass (g),fall,year,reclat,reclong,lat,lon
Aachen,1,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330, 50.775000, 6.083330
Aarhus,2,Valid,H6,720,Fell,01/01/1951 12:00:00 AM,56.183330,10.233330, 56.18333, 10.233330
```

Como restricción **no puedo usar awk ni sed.**

Por el momento, he seleccionado los campos de la siguiente manera:

```
cat df.csv | cut -d ',' -f 1,5,7,8,9,10 | head
```

Output:

```
Aachen,21,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775000; 6.083330)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que el `.csv` está bien formateado con las columnas correspondientes:

1. Mapeamos las siguientes columnas para saber a cual corresponden:

- `name` -> Columna 1
- `id` -> Columna 2
- `nametype` -> Columna 3
- `recclass` -> Columna 4
- `mass (g)` -> Columna 5
- `fall` -> Columna 6
- `year` -> Columna 7
- `reclat` -> Columna 8
- `reclong` -> Columna 9
- `GeoLocation` -> Columna 10

2. Utilizaré un bucle para esto (no veo que lo hayas colocado como una restricción). Dentro del script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usaremos una expresión regular para extraer los dos campos que necesitas de GeoLocation
# Puedes adaptar la regex según como necesites

# Extraemos dos subgrupos, el primero para "lat" y el segundo para "lon"
regex='"\((.*); (.*)\)"'

# Recorremos el fichero, para eso utilizaremos como `internal field separator` la coma
# y colocaremos nombre a cada una de las columnas del fichero:
file='df_one.csv'

# Colocamos un contador:
n=1

# Mientras leemos el fichero, utilizando como separador la coma y asignando a una variable cada columna:
while IFS=, read -r name id nametype recclass mass fall year reclat reclong GeoLocation || [ "$line" ]
do
        # En caso de que sea la primera línea, imprimimos la cabecera:
        if [[ "$n" -eq 1 ]]; then
                echo "$name,$mass,$year,$reclat,$reclong,lat,lon"
                n=$((n+1))
                continue
        fi
        # Utilizamos la expresión regular:
        if [[ $GeoLocation =~ $regex ]]; then
                # Capturamos subgrupos para dividir lat y lon de GeoLocation:
                lat="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
                lon="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        fi
        echo "$name,$mass,$year,$reclat,$reclong,$lat,$lon"
done < $file
```

Si ejecutamos el script:

```
$ -> bash process.sh 
name,mass (g),year,reclat,reclong,lat,lon
Aachen,21,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,50.775000,6.083330
Aarhus,720,01/01/1951 12:00:00 AM,56.183330,10.233330,56.18333,10.233330
```